# The slang meaning of "Seven/七" in Cantonese

Tags: meaning, usage, cantonese, topolect, slang

I have heard a few Hongkongers saying `seven` in a similar, likely identical, context. I assume they are addressing a person because when they say it, they make the `L` hand gesture. I could be wrong, but my intuition is that `seven` is a slang in Cantonese and means something like loser.

Did I guess it right? If not, what is the slang meaning of `seven` in Cantonese? Or is it just a random joke?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the entry `柒` in [Five rude words in Cantonese](http://evchk.wikia.com/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E6%9D%B1%E7%B2%97%E5%8F%A3%E4%BA%94%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%97) and in [this dictionary](http://words.hk/zidin/%E6%9F%92).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a foul character, usually pronounced as "cat6".

The original character is "", which means "scrotum".  On the contrary, in modern slang uses, it refers to the penis in a flaccid state, and is commonly written as "" or "柒".  The implied meaning is thus "useless", "stupid", etc.

Many people tweak the ​​​pronunciation​​​​ from "cat6" to "cat1" (hence, "七"/"柒") to avoid speaking the foul character directly.  Other alternatives like "sat6" (實) are also used.

Comment: any references showing that  is the original character?

Comment: http://zh-yue.wikipedia.org/wiki/%F0%A1%B4%B6